# Share private Google calendar via api

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access a calendar hosted on google via my node application however I am unable to query it via the given api due to my calendar needing authorisation.

How would I go about disabling this/making the calendar accessible to my application?

Here is my api query:
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/heathwallace.com_gpupieshkuc85dd832m9gjrh9g@group.calendar.google.com`

And this is the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: try and set it to public then anyone should be able to access it and you wont need to be authenticated.

Comment: @DaImTo I have tried this already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation [Calendars: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) for example: you will notice it states

> Requires authorization

Now normally if you set something to public you will be able to retrieve it using a public API key.   I took one of my test calendars set it to public then tried to retrieve it using a public API key. (both key and calendar name have been changed)

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/tfaf72h2ubfsftl3h4l5qd87s@group.calendar.google.com?key=AIzaSyBBH88dIQPjcl5nIG-n1mmuQ12J7HThDBL

results are

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

**Conclusion:** You must be authenticated to retrieve data.  Either using OAuth2 or a service account.  Normally I would suggest you use a service account and grant it access to the Calendar in question.  I would not use a service account with JavaScript due to security issues, so I cant help you with that.

**Answer** to your question you must be authenticated to see a calendar. there is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this actually (no Oauth required).
The piece of magic is to create a developer key in the developer console console.developers.google.com (in the APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> Public Access Key -> Key for server app)

Make sure to have the calendar API enabled in the console again (APIs & Auth -> Apis)

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/heathwallace.com_gpupieshkuc85dd832m9gjrh9g%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I've just successfully retrieved your calendar that way.